# How to use TrangularView class in Eigen C++

Tags: linear-solver, c++, eigen

For a nonsingular lower or upper triangular square matrix $A$, how to solve such linear system in Eigen:

$$A x = b$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documented [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__QuickRefPage.html#title14):

```
x = A.triangularView<Upper>().solve(b);
```

or

```
x = A.triangularView<Lower>().solve(b);
```

Comment: thank you for answering so many of my `Eigen` related questions!